# Check if a user-defined type already exists in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-types

Say I have created some user-defined types in the DB,

i.e. `CREATE TYPE abc ...`

Is it then possible to determine if the user-defined type exists or not? Perhaps, using any of the postgres information tables?

The main reason for this is since PostgreSQL does not seem to support `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ...`, and if a certain type gets created more than once, I want to be able to drop the existing one first, then re-load the new one.

Comment: You know that you cannot drop or replace a type if it is still used by a table?

Comment: In case you want to avoid ERROR in a transaction for a type you already created in a previous attempt of failed transaction, you could always DROP TYPE IF EXISTS just before the creation statement.

Comment: Anyhow you can find the best answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64401873/check-if-a-custom-type-is-installed-in-a-schema @user330315

Answer (score 137):

I add here the complete solution for creating types in a simple script, without the need of creating a function just for this purpose.

```
--create types
DO $$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'my_type') THEN
        CREATE TYPE my_type AS
        (
            --my fields here...
        );
    END IF;
    --more types here...
END$$;
```

Comment: This isn't quite correct when using schemas, as the fact that a type exists in the pg_type table doesn't necessarily mean that it exists in any schemas in the current search path. ISTM that you need to select on typnamespace too, but I'm not sure how yet.

Comment: @Cromax See my somewhat simpler [simpler version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48382296/41344) of your answer.

Comment: @rog Seems plausible. 8) And it is not PSQL's features dependent (like `regtype`), so it seem to be actually better solution. 8)

Comment: Why think so many this is the only and best answer? If i go with it answer and run a create type on a database with one version of the type, with this sql my old type never ever changed. From the question its clear, that the type we need is may or may not exists in the db.

Comment: This one didn't work for me, so I went with EXCEPTION.

Comment: @jamesvl rather than editing an existing answer to change it, please either suggest the change to the author in a comment or post your own answer.

Comment: No need for `SELECT 1` when using `EXISTS`, it can just be `SELECT FROM pg_type ...`.

Answer (score 125):

The simplest solution I've found so far that copes with schemas, inspired by @Cromax's answer, is this:

```
DO $$ BEGIN
    CREATE TYPE my_type AS (/* fields go here */);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN duplicate_object THEN null;
END $$;
```

Just what you might expect really - we just wrap the CREATE TYPE statement in an exception handler so it doesn't abort the current transaction.

Comment: This is the only example that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I am completely new to this language and I want to do something similar, but not overload an existing type. So I want to check if a type exists and if not, create it. I'm not sure what the `EXCEPTION` here means. Is the type then already overloaded or I can use this as is?

Comment: when I do this from DBeaver sql workbench tool, it works perfectly. But if I try running it in python psycopg2 as inside a cursor.execute(), it fails. How do I do this programmatically?

Comment: Correct-me if I'm wring but this approach swallows any kind of error that may occur upon type creation. The case of the already existing type but not only. You then lose information on what went wrong if the type did not already exist but could not be created either.

Answer (score 58):

Indeed, Postgres does not have `CREATE OR REPLACE` functionality for types. So the best approach is to drop it:

```
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS YOUR_TYPE;
CREATE TYPE YOUR_TYPE AS (
    id      integer,
    field   varchar
);
```

Simple solution is always the best one.

Comment: What if that type is currently used by a table?

Comment: @Shane Then `DROP` will throw an error. You can use, however `DROP ... CASCADE` to drop also dependent objects—if loosing data in that particular case is acceptable.

Comment: I'd suggest that many folks (myself included) are automatically averse to mechanisms with even a whiff of data loss about them. So, although simple solutions often are the best, this may be a counterexample.

Comment: The question was 'Check if a user-defined type already exists in PostgreSQL' so to try to drop the type is absolutely not an answer.

Comment: Good luck handling this on production servers with migrations

Answer (score 33):

You can look in the [`pg_type`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-type.html) table:

```
select exists (select 1 from pg_type where typname = 'abc');
```

If that is true then `abc` exists.

Comment: For people coming to this solution from google, there is a small caveat to this approach. If you have created a type in a schema say "my_schema", then the condition will still return true even if you are checking in another schema. The complete query would be `select exists (select 1 from pg_type where typname = 'abc' and typnamespace = (select oid from pg_namespace where nspname = 'my_schema'))`. Replace 'my_schema' with 'public' if you are using a single-schema configuration.

Comment: ***ATTENTION***: It's *typ* NOT typ**E**name!

Comment: @testing_22 Had difficulties intentionally misspelling "type"? Almost as annoying as "referer" in HTTP headers.

Comment: I did! Also as irritating as `umount` when working with disk partitions!! Yikes!

Answer (score 17):

To solve @rog's dilemma to @bluish's answer it could be more appropriate to make use of `regtype` data type. Consider this:

```
DO $$ BEGIN
    PERFORM 'my_schema.my_type'::regtype;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN undefined_object THEN
        CREATE TYPE my_schema.my_type AS (/* fields go here */);
END $$;
```

`PERFORM` clause is like `SELECT`, but it discards results, so basically we're checking if it is possible to cast `'my_schema.my_type'` (or just `'my_type'` if you don't care to be schema specific) to actual registered type. If the type does exist, then nothing "wrong" will happen and whole block will end—no changes, since the type `my_type` is already there. But if the cast is not possible, then there will be thrown an error of code `42704` which has label of `undefined_object`. So in the next lines we try to catch that error and if that happens, we simply create our new data type.

Comment: Excellent explanation, thank you!  This seems by far the best answer here; shame it hasn't gotten more attention.

Comment: Thank you, you're welcome. Please see also @rog's reworked answer, it's shorter. One drawback (as from my POV) it has, is slower execution, if the checks happen more than once, because of throwing and catching the exception every time the type exists (and after first execution it will exist). But it may be not that important after all. 8)

Comment: Please see also @Hans Brende answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69511680/2024692)—I find it better than my proposal. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Inspired by @Cromax's answer, here's an alternative solution using the system catalog information function [`to_regtype`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#id-1.5.8.32.19.2.2.35.1.1.1) that avoids [the extra overhead of an exception clause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/233394/208235) but still checks the correct schema for the type's existence:

```
DO $$ BEGIN
    IF to_regtype('my_schema.abc') IS NULL THEN
        CREATE TYPE my_schema.abc ... ;
    END IF;
END $$;
```

In the case of the default `public` schema being used, it would look like:

```
DO $$ BEGIN
    IF to_regtype('abc') IS NULL THEN
        CREATE TYPE abc ... ;
    END IF;
END $$;
```

Comment: +1 according to the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) `The regclass input converter handles the table lookup according to the schema path setting`...this means `regtype` (which is equivalent to the `to_regtype` function used in the code for this answer) will also respect the schema path setting and you can do `SET schema_path = my_schema;`  then do `IF to_regtype('abc') IS NULL...` and will work just as if you wrote `my_schema.abc`. This is useful if you set the schema path to help avoid repeating the schema name all over the place.

Comment: I find this solution better than mine. :-)  Good one! :-)

Answer (score 6):

```
-- All of this to create a type if it does not exist
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_abc_type() RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE v_exists INTEGER;

BEGIN
    SELECT into v_exists (SELECT 1 FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'abc');
    IF v_exists IS NULL THEN
        CREATE TYPE abc AS ENUM ('height', 'weight', 'distance');
    END IF;
    RETURN v_exists;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Call the function you just created
SELECT create_abc_type();

-- Remove the function you just created
DROP function create_abc_type();
-----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

A more generic solution

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_type(name text, _type text) RETURNS 
integer AS $$
DECLARE v_exists INTEGER;

BEGIN
    SELECT into v_exists (SELECT 1 FROM pg_type WHERE typname = name);
    IF v_exists IS NULL THEN
            EXECUTE format('CREATE TYPE %I AS %s', name, _type);
    END IF;
    RETURN v_exists;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and then you can call it like this:

`select create_type('lwm2m_instancetype', 'enum (''single'',''multiple'')');`

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do the same thing, ensure a type exists.

I started psql with the `--echo-hidden` (`-E`) option and entered `\dT`:

```
$ psql -E
psql (9.1.9)
testdb=> \dT
********* QUERY **********
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  pg_catalog.format_type(t.oid, NULL) AS "Name",
  pg_catalog.obj_description(t.oid, 'pg_type') as "Description"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_type t
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.typnamespace
WHERE (t.typrelid = 0 OR (SELECT c.relkind = 'c' FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c WHERE c.oid = t.typrelid))
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_type el WHERE el.oid = t.typelem AND el.typarray = t.oid)
      AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
      AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
  AND pg_catalog.pg_type_is_visible(t.oid)
ORDER BY 1, 2;
**************************
 List of data types
 Schema |       Name       | Description 
--------+------------------+-------------
 public | errmsg_agg_state | 
(1 row)
```

If you are using schemas and search_path (I am) then you'll probably need to keep the `pg_catalog.pg_type_is_visible(t.oid)` check.  I don't know what all the conditions in the WHERE are doing, but they didn't seem relevant to my case. Currently using:

```
SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_type as t
   WHERE typname = 'mytype' AND pg_catalog.pg_type_is_visible(t.oid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative

```
WITH namespace AS(
    SELECT oid 
        FROM pg_namespace 
        WHERE nspname = 'my_schema'
),
type_name AS (
    SELECT 1 type_exist  
        FROM pg_type 
        WHERE typname = 'my_type' AND typnamespace = (SELECT * FROM namespace)
)
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM type_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

This plays well with schemas, and avoids exception handling:

```sql
DO $$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM pg_type t
      LEFT JOIN pg_namespace p ON t.typnamespace=p.oid
      WHERE t.typname='my_type' AND p.nspname='my_schema'
    ) THEN
        CREATE TYPE my_schema.my_type AS (/* fields go here */);
    END IF;
END
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
SELECT * from pg_enum WHERE enumlabel='WHAT YOU WANT';
```

Answer (score 0):

Continue with bluish code, we also need to check if DB has such a type in current schema. Because current code will not create type if db has same type in any of db schemas. So full universal code will look like this:

````
$$
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(select 
                      from pg_type
                      WHERE typname = 'YOUR_ENUM_NAME'
                        AND typnamespace in
                            (SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace where nspname = "current_schema"())) THEN
            CREATE TYPE YOUR_ENUM_NAME AS ENUM (....list of values ....);
        END IF;
    END
$$;```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer here [Check if a custom type is installed in a schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64401873/check-if-a-custom-type-is-installed-in-a-schema)

```
SELECT 1
FROM pg_type 
WHERE typname = 'your_custom_type'
  and typnamespace = 'your_schema_containing_custom_type'::regnamespace
```

Thanks the answer to @user330315

Comment: I just have catched the answer from @Panchove which is simple and perfect as well so I have upvoted that one.