# Create a type if not exist Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to run this sql which create a new type if is is not existed:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'ai') CREATE TYPE ai AS (a text, i int);
```

I got an error at or near "if", I have trying to find out the answer but its no help. I tried this also but it still not work:

```
CASE (SELECT 1 FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'ai') WHEN IS NULL THEN CREATE TYPE ai AS (a text, i int);
```

error near or at "CASE"

Comment: There's no `IF` in SQL (at least in postgres).

Comment: i updated question with case when

Comment: This is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7624919/192740).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `IF` syntax is wrong, it misses `END IF`. Depending on the context, i.e. when you're not already in an PL/pgSQL block (like a function etc.), you need to also use an anonymous `DO` block. And don't forget to check for the schema too, otherwise you might get false positives if the type already exists in another schema.

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                        FROM pg_type typ
                             INNER JOIN pg_namespace nsp
                                        ON nsp.oid = typ.typnamespace
                        WHERE nsp.nspname = current_schema()
                              AND typ.typname = 'ai') THEN
    CREATE TYPE ai
                AS (a text,
                    i integer);
  END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

(Or, if you're already in an PL/pgSQL block, just everything between `IF` and `END IF;` including `IF` and `END IF;`.)

Comment: I include IF and END IF but i still got a syntax error near if

Comment: Then you may have something wrong before the `IF`. What I posted works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=a67097b1731d93037623bdd07bc5d6ff