# Check if a custom type is installed in a schema

Tags: postgresql

I know that I can make a query in `pg_type` table for check if any type exists, like that:

```
SELECT 1 FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'mycustomtype'
```

But if this *customtype* exists in other schema different to the schema I want to install it, I´ll get a true, and then a script like that won´t work:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'task_status') THEN
        CREATE TYPE task_status AS ENUM ('todo', 'doing', 'blocked', 'done');
    END IF;
END
$$;
```

I want to use this script into the scripts of an extension, but it can fail if there are a type with the same name but in other schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the schema name in your WHERE condition:

```
SELECT true
FROM pg_type 
WHERE typname = 'mycustomtype'
  and typnamespace = 'your_schema'::regnamespace
```

---

> *I want to use this script into the scripts of an extension*

You should set the search_path in your extension's script if you want to make your [extension relocatable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-extensions.html#EXTEND-EXTENSIONS-RELOCATION)

In that case you probably should use:

```
SELECT true
FROM pg_type 
WHERE typname = 'mycustomtype'
  and typnamespace = '@extschema@'::regnamespace
```

To check the existence in the schema specified during `create extension`

Comment: Sorry. What do it mean @extschema@?

Comment: Please see the link I provided, it explains it