# Not sure why I am getting this result in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to convert a MySQL database to PostgreSQL and I created this

```
CREATE TYPE location_m as enum('England','Japan','France','Usa','China','Canada');

CREATE TABLE airport (
  id int NOT NULL,
  owner varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  location location_m NOT NULL DEFAULT 'England',
  travel_prices varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '100-100-100-100-100-100',
  profit varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0-0-0-0-0-0'
) ;

INSERT INTO airport (id, owner, location, travel_prices, profit) VALUES
(1, 'Mafia', 'Japan', '1000-1000-1000-1000-1000-1000', '0-18000-34000-15500-11000-13000');
```

What I run the insert it returns with this

> psql:main_db.sql:43: ERROR:  type "location_m" already exists

I tried looking it up but can't really find anything. I don't understand why it is saying it already exists.

I thought I was doing the enum correctly based on the docs and the other Stack Overflow posts.

Comment: Can you check if you haven't created the enum before? I tried running these queries in my system and it worked fine, but if I tried running them again, I got the same error.

Comment: Hi thank you for replying. That is my entire file so far, it makes no sense to me. its been driving me mad lol. I have 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS airport;

at the beginning.

Comment: `select exists (select 1 from pg_type where typname = 'location_m');` Try running this query in your postgresql database, if it returns true, that would mean that the location_m type has already been created.

Comment: So, it returns a     t, but here is what I do not understand. I dropped all the tables and made sure there is no table before I ran it, is it because I am just dropping tables and not recreating the enums?

Comment: You are dropping the tables, but enum types are somewhat different, they are stored in a table called `pg_type` which is not a user table, so it won't get dropped when you drop other tables. You can either remove the location_m enum by `delete from pg_type where typname = 'location_m';` for which you might need admin access or you can remove the first query from your file.

Comment: @PraveenRewar Don't run `DELETE` on system tables. Just use [`DROP TYPE IF EXISTS location_m;`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-droptype.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That is my entire file so far, except I have `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS airport;` at the beginning.

If you're doing that, you will also want to place a [`DROP TYPE IF EXISTS location_m;`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-droptype.html) at the beginning of the script. (Possibly with the `CASCADE` option if it's already used in a table definition, or make sure to drop all such tables first).

Alternatively, have a look at [Check if a user-defined type already exists in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624919/check-if-a-user-defined-type-already-exists-in-postgresql) for various other workarounds for `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE …`, although if you are working with a migration script that will run only once and expect an empty database, it's probably no harm to just drop and recreate them.

Answer (score 0):

A far better idea, use 2 scripts. Put your creates in 1 script, it gets run 1 time. The other script contains only the Insert. If needed delete and re-run as many times as needed. Further IMHO never use 'if exists' on ddl, keep in mind that **errors can be your friend**. Consider the following scenario.  
Your script:

```
drop type if exists  location_m cascade;
create type location_m as enum('England','Japan','France','Usa','China','Canada');

drop table if exists  airport ;
create table airport (
  id int not null,
  owner varchar(40) not null default '',
  location location_m not null default 'England',
  travel_prices varchar(100) not null default '100-100-100-100-100-100',
  profit varchar(100) not null default '0-0-0-0-0-0'
) ;

insert into airport (id, owner, location, travel_prices, profit) VALUES
(1, 'Mafia', 'Japan', '1000-1000-1000-1000-1000-1000', '0-18000-34000-15500-11000-13000');
```

The another developer in your organization working on a different project, but using the same naming conventions comes along with their script:

```
drop type if exists  location_m cascade;
create type location_m as enum('USA', 'Canada', 'Brazil');
 
 create table hotel( id integer generated always as identity
                   , name      text  
                   , location  location_m not null default 'Canada'
                   , corporate_rate money
                   ) ;
```

Now what does the following give you?

```
select * 
  from airport
  where location = 'Japan';
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2e57818ff0c73a55bc673d5cf96c9448) here. So what happened? Have fun trying to find this why this happened. Oh well never mind just rerun your script. But soon you are both posting to SO wanting to know what Postgres bug in causing your problem - even though the problem is not on the Postgres side at all.