# enum type create with skip logic working in workbench but not in program with psycopg2 execute

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Postgresql query to create an enum type in postgresql, and skip over if its already created:

```sql
DO $$ BEGIN
    CREATE TYPE operated_by_enum AS ENUM ('opA', 'opB');
EXCEPTION
    WHEN duplicate_object THEN null;
END $$;
```

courtesy https://stackoverflow.com/a/48382296/4355695

This works perfectly from DBeaver hooked to my Postgres DB which is latest version. The enum in question is already existing, so this skips over.

However, if I run the same query in my python program, then it fails with:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 11: IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'operat...
```

The sql executing code is as follows:

```py
connection = psycopg2.connect(**DB_PARAMETERS)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(s1)
cursor.commit()
cursor.close()
```

s1 here being a string variable having the above sql block.

Why is this behaving differently in the different places? Prior to this I've done a variety of SQL statements and they've all worked the same whether in program or in the workbench tool. Then why here is there a difference?

I haven't studied PostgreSQL intensely enough to understand $$ and BEGIN-END terms completely, from surface level I reckon they're for executing block statements instead of one by one. I've seen that just removing (BEGIN .. END) or (do $$ .. $$) from the sql makes it fail in the workbench.

I've tried similarly with the other way also shared:
`SELECT 1 FROM pg_type WHERE typname`
Getting same failure result when I try to do it from program.

Could there be something in psycopg2 that strips those block keywords away or something?

Not able to make out much from the pysopg2 documentation: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html

Finally, I'm looking for a way to execute an enum type creation statement in a python program such that it politely skips over in case it's already there, and it's part of a larger set of DB schema setup statements (creating tables and all).

---

**Edit:** I found that I can just do DROP followed by re CREATE:

```
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS operated_by_enum;
CREATE TYPE operated_by_enum AS ENUM ('opA', 'opB');
```

The caveat being that there should be no existing columns in any table belonging to this type at the time. For me this was fine as I was dropping and recreating that table also anyways. I simply inserted above 2 lines after the table drop and before its recreate.

My question was specific to another action, and there may be a valid use case where dropping the enum isn't an option. So. leaving the question up. But for those whose situation allows for dropping, I'll suggest taking this much simpler way.

Comment: Your syntax error and your example input don't seem to match. However, `psycopg2` might not understand dollar quoting. Therefore, you can replace the `$$` with `'`. However, you will have to escape any string literals with a double, single quote. EX: `DO ' BEGIN CREATE TYPE operated_by_enum AS ENUM (''opA'', ''opB''); ' END;`

Comment: For the `pg_type` example, you can try something like `IF NOT SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'your_type_name'); THEN CREATE TYPE ... END IF;` Or just `SELECT * FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'your_type_name'; IF NOT FOUND THEN CREATE TYPE ... END IF;`