# Alembic - Error :Type "gender" already exists

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm running a migration script for a table using alembic. In the first script, I created a Table users and created a ENUM dataype called gender_scripts. The script worked. In next migration script, I tried to created a New table that referenced the Table users. But the sql generated for this script, had the following .

`CREATE TYPE gender_types AS ENUM ('male', 'female', 'non_binary');`

But , the datatype is already present from the first script. how to fix this.

I tried changing the first script to a if block to check whether the type already existed. but that didn't work.

Comment: What have you tried, did you take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28274121/4388775 ?

Comment: definition of gender hasn't changed between migrations.

Comment: @L.Meyer I tried running that sql via psql and it worked , but when I run it via alembic, It is not working. I removed the created of gender type from intial migration but after that it raised a error saying the users table (table created from first intial script exists). I don't know what error is this. It should exist because it is the first migration script. when i try to create a migration script that access already existing table as a foreign key. The sql generated shows it is creating a table that already exists. Why it happens /